# Errors when trying to create and use a random permutation test function in R

Tags: r, function, error-code

I am trying to complete a random permutation test in RStudio and keep getting the following two errors:
Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?

```
#create groups/data vectors
drinks = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
mosquito = c(27, 20, 21, 26, 27, 3, 24, 21, 20, 19, 23, 24, 28, 19, 24, 29, 18, 20, 17, 31, 20, 25, 28, 21, 27, 21, 22, 15, 12, 21, 19, 15, 22, 24, 19, 23, 13, 22, 20, 24, 18, 20)

#create function
rpermut = function(group, outcome, permutation){
diff = rep(NA, permutation)
for(i in 1:permutation){
outcome = sample(outcome)
diff[i] = mean(outcome[group==levels(group)[1]]) - mean(outcome[group==levels(group)[2]])}
diff
}

#adding values to function
mosrep = rpermut(group=drinks, outcome=mosquito, permutation=1000)
```

I am not sure what the error codes mean nor how to fix things so that the function will run. I would greatly appreciate any assistance you may be able to provide on where I am going wrong here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems to work for me with a few changes.
Firstly I assume that both drinks and mosquito should be the same length which in your question is not the case.

```
> length(drinks)
[1] 43
> length(mosquito)
[1] 42
```

Secondly, levels() works on factors whereas those objects drinks and mosquito are numeric vectors.

```
> class(drinks)
[1] "numeric"
> class(mosquito)
[1] "numeric"
```

to therefore make this function work on my machine i had to then adjust the function to be this:

```
rpermut = function(group, outcome, permutation){
    diff = c()
    group = as.factor(group)
    for(i in 1:permutation){
        outcome = sample(outcome)
        diff[i] = mean(outcome[group==levels(group)[1]]) - mean(outcome[group==levels(group)[2]])
    }
    return(diff)
}
```

This is just changing the group to a factor with `as.factor()`

I also changed `diff = rep(NA, permutation)` to just `diff = c()` which is creating an empty vector. There is no need to assign NA to all the values as you can simply fill an entry with `diff[i]` the same way.

So the vectors need to be the same length and then this should work, a check could simply be added as well.

```
if(length(group) != length(outcome)){
        stop("input vector lengths does not match!")
    }
```

All together:

```
rpermut = function(group, outcome, permutation){
    if(length(group) != length(outcome)){
        stop("input vector lengths does not match!")
    }
    diff = c()
    group = as.factor(group)
    for(i in 1:permutation){
        outcome = sample(outcome)
        diff[i] = mean(outcome[group==levels(group)[1]]) - mean(outcome[group==levels(group)[2]])
    }
    return(diff)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm just trying to learn this coding and really appreciate your assistance!